# Iterating between 2 lists while adding content from one to the other in Python

Tags: python, list

If I have the following lists:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = ['1','2','3']
```

How can I get python to output this:

```
['a',1,'b',2,'c',3]
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['1', '2', '3']

c = []
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    c.append(x)
    c.append(y)

print (c)
```

output:

```
['a', '1', 'b', '2', 'c', '3']
```

Of course you can change it to match your needs, if needed

Comment: One liner: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b)))`